# How To check if data exsist in Array of Firebase with Php

Tags: php, firebase

I have a Field in a document called Technicals that contain 3 value (3 names of technicals) I need to check if a specific technical is involved in a specific problem how can I do this with PHP

[image: firebase table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the Firebase documentation on [querying for array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#php_7) that'd be something like this:

```
$containsQuery = $collectionRef->where('Technical', 'array-contains', 'your value');
```